# How to build 2 device drivers with a small amount of shared code

Tags: windows, build, wdk

I've inherited a Windows driver that handles multiple device types.  I need to separate it into 2 separated drivers, one for each device.  There's code for each device, and then code that is common to the two, and so I've made 3 directories: deviceA, deviceB and common.

I've done this for 2 reasons:
  1. it just seems more clear to separate the drivers sources this way
  2. build.exe requires a 'sources' file, and so I couldn't have separate files for the 2 drivers in the same directory

Using Visual Studio to invoke ddkbuild.bat, my build fails miserably.

Is possible to do this the way I'm attempting?  Is there a better/smarter way?

I've modified *sources* in each device subdirectory.  I don't know **what** to do about the common files.

Using Visual Studio 2008, ddkbuild, DDK 7600.16385.0.

Comment: What did you do for sources in the common directory?  How did your build fail?  There are lots of reasons that this isn't working, we need more specific information to provide any sort of answer.

Comment: I haven't done anything (yet) for *common/sources*.  My driverUSB wouldn't compile at all.  I'm at the point now where driverUSB does compile but obviously won't link due to the files that moved to common.  So now I guess my question is: what **should** I do for *common/sources*?  *sources* implies that I use build.exe, which (I think) implies ddkbuild.bat.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static library to solve this problem. I'm not sure about ddkbuild.bat, what happens when you open the DDK Command Prompt and type `build -C -Z`?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  "fails miserably" probably wasn't helpful (I had 6000+ errors and was getting frustrated).  It turns out that the compile errors were mostly my errors: 1 - I'd split a header into 3 (common, A and B, where A and B #include common), but neglected to change some source files to include their respective headers, 2 - I hadn't told VC++ about the additional include path argument to nmake, and 3 - I found elsewhere on the Web that build.exe doesn't like to have pathnames with spaces ("Documents and Settings").  Working now on Paul's suggested static library for common.

Comment: Thanks again ... I haven't installed and tested my new drivers yet, but they both build fine.  As you suggested, I created a static lib for the shared code and linked the individual drivers with it.